# NextJs app error while creating Api Routes import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises'; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, next.js

I want it to read the json in utf format and display in terminal

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

export default function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile("/blogdata/how-to-learnjavascript.json","utf-8",(err,data)=>{console.log(data)})
    res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
  }
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Have you tried doing: ```import fs from 'node:fs';``` ? 
Have you tried ```const fs = require('node:fs');``` ?

Comment: @tgdn i am using esscript syntax

Comment: i updated the package.json file and included a key type and gave it the value of module it is not throwing any error and also not displaying any out put at all

Comment: Is your file located correctly at ```/pages/api/yourfile.js``` ? If this is an api route, it should be placed there.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use `fs` module in `Next.js`.You can only do **FS-related** operations while on the server, within `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`

---

Here You Have simple example how to use `fs` and `path` module with `getStaticProps`:

**index.js** (home page)

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export default function Home({ data }) {
  const persons = data.persons;
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 30 }}>
      <h1>Example Next.js & Node.js FS module</h1>
      <div>
        {persons.map((person) => (
          <div
            key={person.id}
            style={{ padding: 20, borderBottom: "1px solid #ccc" }}
          >
            <h2>{person.name}</h2>
            <p>{person.email}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const dataFilePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "data.json");
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(dataFilePath, "utf8");

  const data = JSON.parse(fileContents);
  console.log(data);

  return { props: { data } };
}
```

---

**data.json**

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "dolores",
            "email": "dolores@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ed",
            "email": "ed@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "james",
            "email": "james007@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "joda",
            "email": "joda-jedi@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Output(*server side*) folder and file structure**:

[image]

---

**Output browser**:

[image]

*Tested with "next": "12.1.6"*

Comment: I think OP is talking about an api route, and your comment is about a react component within a page route.

Comment: @tgdn next.js component.... and use case  `fs` module on server side `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` functions ;-) Btw Do You know how to use `fs` module in api route (next.js) ???

Comment: @tgdn and Why we can / could use fs module in API next.js ? Any specific useful examples?

Comment: As @tgdn mentioned, OP's code suggests they're using an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) which runs on the server, and where it's perfectly fine to use Node.js libraries like `fs`.

Comment: @juliomalves Okay. Thanks very much for your reference and info ! See ya;-)